# Counting number of current checked boxes and output that number in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am trying to count the number of the current checked "checked box" in a group box. I have like 10 check boxes.

I been trying some code but I only managed to count upward if I checked the box but not the other way around. So it is only adding up (but not +1 each time).

So what approach do I have to take to count the number of the current (not incrementing) checked boxes? Thank you

```
int checkedBoxes = 0;

private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool result = check.Checked;

    if (result == true)
    {
        btnDone.Enabled = true;
    }

    foreach (Control c in grpToppings.Controls)
    {
        CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            checkedBoxes += 1;
            int how_many = checkedBoxes;
        }
    }
}

private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = textbox_orderName.Text;
    MessageBox.Show("\nhow many: " + checkedBoxes, "It is done",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code more readably - it's all over the place at the moment. If it's like that in your IDE (Visual Studio?) you should be able to ask the IDE to format it for you... then copy/paste into Stack Overflow, select all of the code and press Ctrl-K.

Comment: Next: rather than counting in the click method, why not just count when the "done" button is pressed? No need for a field...

Comment: Short and easy: `int how_many = grpToppings.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(cb => cb.Checked);`

Comment: You are NOT resetting the counter checkedBoxes to 0 before the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the assignment of `checkedBoxes` in the event `checkBox1_Click` as you are looping over all the child controls again and count should be reset.

```
int checkedBoxes;

private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedBoxes = 0;
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool result = check.Checked;

    if (result == true)
    {
        btnDone.Enabled = true;
    }

    foreach (Control c in grpToppings.Controls)
    {
        CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            checkedBoxes += 1;
            int how_many = checkedBoxes;
        }
    }
}
```